# Image condition is not getting evaluated after publishing the report

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I created a report that has a some image components that are presented according to an expression that evaluates a field value and prints the corresponding image as follows:

```
$F{cop_overall_status}== null ? "C:\\imgpath\\stoplightWhite.png" : 
$F{cop_overall_status}<= 10 ? "C:\\imgpath\\stoplightGreen.png" : 
$F{cop_overall_status}<= 20 ? "C:\\imgpath\\stoplightYellow.png" :
"C:\\imgpath\\stoplightRed.png"
```

All the image components are working fine in the Studio (JSS) "preview", but when i export the report to JasperReports Server (JRS) some of those images do not get correctly evaluated here is the results from:

JSS preview:

[image]

JRS output:

[image]

I've tryed to re-create the images but everythime i do this the image i re-created gets fixed but another one gets the same bug, where the expression is not correctly evaluated and displays a white diamond.

Comment: Did you try to use another image? Did you try to simplify an expression?

Comment: `where the expression is not correctly evaluated` - Why do you think so? Did you check the `$F{cop_overall_status} == null` expression with textField?

Comment: Yes the text field shows the value correctly. How can i simplify the expression?

Comment: I mean for testing purpose. You should post the snippet from *jrxml* with *image* declaration. Did you post screenshot of JRS page? Did you try to export report to *pdf*, for example? Do you have the same issue at exported file?

Comment: The result is the same when i export to pdf or any other format, as shown in JRS output.

Comment: And yes its a screenshot of the report execution in jasperserver, with the same parameters as the studio preview.